# Ansible crreate dict and double loop a list which has a vraible list

Tags: ansible

I have this variable

```
result:
    results:
    - ansible_loop_var: item
      item: /bigdata/gidn/data/input/datalake/test_workspace_3
      stdout: |2-
 
        snapshot_input
      stdout_lines:
      - ''
      - snapshot_input
    - ansible_loop_var: item
      item: /bigdata/gidn/data/output/datalake/test_workspace_3
      stdout: |2-
 
        snapshot_output
      stdout_lines:
      - ''
      - snapshot_output
    - ansible_loop_var: item
      item: /bigdata/gidn/projets/datalake/test_workspace_3
      stdout: |2-
 
        snapshot_projet_1
        snapshot_projet_2
      stdout_lines:
      - ''
      - snapshot_projet_1
      - snapshot_projet_2
```

I wanted to loop over result.results and of each item, I loop again over stdout_lines and create a dict like this :

```
{'path': /bigdata/gidn/data/input/datalake/test_workspace_3, 'id':snapshot_input},{'path': /bigdata/gidn/data/output/datalake/test_workspace_3, 'id':snapshot_output},{'path': /bigdata/gidn/projets/datalake/test_workspace_3, 'id':snapshot_projet_1},{'path': /bigdata/gidn/projets/datalake/test_workspace_3, 'id':snapshot_projet_2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible doesn't support nested loops directly, but we can fake it using things like the [`subelements` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_filter.html), like this:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    result:
        results:
        - ansible_loop_var: item
          item: /bigdata/gidn/data/input/datalake/test_workspace_3
          stdout: |2-
    
            snapshot_input
          stdout_lines:
          - ''
          - snapshot_input
        - ansible_loop_var: item
          item: /bigdata/gidn/data/output/datalake/test_workspace_3
          stdout: |2-
    
            snapshot_output
          stdout_lines:
          - ''
          - snapshot_output
        - ansible_loop_var: item
          item: /bigdata/gidn/projects/datalake/test_workspace_3
          stdout: |2-
    
            snapshot_project_1
            snapshot_project_2
          stdout_lines:
          - ''
          - snapshot_project_1
          - snapshot_project_2

  tasks:
    - loop: "{{ result.results|subelements('stdout_lines')}}"
      when: item.1
      vars:
        myvar: []
      set_fact:
        myvar: "{{ myvar + [{'path': item.0.item, 'id': item.1}]}}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ myvar }}"
```

This will produce the following output:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "id": "snapshot_input",
            "path": "/bigdata/gidn/data/input/datalake/test_workspace_3"
        },
        {
            "id": "snapshot_output",
            "path": "/bigdata/gidn/data/output/datalake/test_workspace_3"
        },
        {
            "id": "snapshot_project_1",
            "path": "/bigdata/gidn/projects/datalake/test_workspace_3"
        },
        {
            "id": "snapshot_project_2",
            "path": "/bigdata/gidn/projects/datalake/test_workspace_3"
        }
    ]
}
```

(NB: In your question you say, "I want to create a dict like this...", but the example you show is a *list* of dictionaries, which is what I have produced here.)